# Iterate over pairs of two files in a directory

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

I have a directory full of files named
 `foo-1.ocf`
 `foo-2.ocf`
 `bar-1.ocf`
 `bar-2.ocf`
 `file-1.ocf`
 `file-2.ocf`
I want to iterate over each pair of files, if bot files exist (`-1.ocf` and `-2.ocf`).
What is a good approach to do this in boost?

Comment: What's supposed to happen if there's only one file of the pair?

Comment: @jrok you do not include it in your iteration :)

Comment: @SelçukCihan Or maybe stop the iteration completely? I'd rather have OP clarify this.

Comment: If a file occurs, for which there is no "partner", just drop that file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Obtain a sorted list of files, here's [a tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Using-path-decomposition).
2. Run through that list remembering (a) if the previous file had suffix `-1` and (b) the prefix of the previous file.
3. So if current file has the same prefix as the previous, and the previous file had suffix `-1`, and current file has suffix `-2` - then you got another pair of files.